# XSLT beginner - not sure how to apply template

Tags: xml, xslt

If I have the following XML:

```
<items>
  <item>
    <subItem>
      <name>myName</name>
    </subitem>
    <subitem>
      <val>Val1</val>
      <val>Val2</val>
    </subItem>
  </item>
  <item>
     ...more tags here
  </item> 
</items>
```

The item element repeats a number of times with different values. If I know the value in the val element I want to match, for instance Val1, what do I use for a template to select the name element value myName in the subItem above it?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
item[subItem/val='value']
```

This says "select an item that contains a subitem/val whose text content is 'value'"

Answer (score 0):

I myself have not had to perform this same selection.  Without knowing more about the context of why you're doing this, I'm presuming you want the previous sibling of the selected XML element.

With that said, this blog post might help you out: [Using XPath's 'preceding-sibling' Axis Correctly](http://www.infopathdev.com/blogs/greg/archive/2005/06/13/Using-XPath_2700_s-_2700_preceding_2D00_sibling_2700_-Axis-Correctly.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

So basically I think what you really wanted is :

```
//val[. = 'Val1' and parent::subItem]/parent::subItem/preceding-sibling::subItem[1]/name
```

Which will select all `val` elements who are children of `subItem` and have a specified value, in this case `Val1` and then navigate to the name of the preceding `subItem` element. You can adjust it to better suit your need of course.

Answer (score 0):

The provided XML isn't well-formed: the `<subItem>` start tag has a `</subitem>` closing tag and the next `<subitem>` start tag has a `<subItem>` closing tag.

**Remember that XML names are case sensitive**!

Provided that the malformedness issues are fixed and only lowercase names are used in the corrected, well-formed document,

**Use as a match pattern**:

```
item[subitem/val = 'Val1']/subitem/name
```

This matches any `name` element that is a chid of a `subitem` that is a child of an `item` that has at least one `subitem` child that has at least one `val` child with string value `"Val1"`.

**The `xsl:template` instruction is**:

```
<xsl:template match="item[subitem/val = 'Val1']/subitem/name">
  <!-- Any desired processing here -->
</xsl:template>
```

**Do note**:

This solution is independent of the ordering of the `subitem` elements and will work  correctly even if they are reordered and, say, the `subitem` that has a `name` child is the last of all `subitem` children.